# How do I set a default window size through Compiz (CCSM)?

Tags: compiz, ccsm

I am on 11.10. I feel a bit stupid, but I cannot find it. How do I set a default size of a window? There must be something in CCSM. I would for example like if gnome-terminal were always 1000 pixels high.

This is how my Windows Rules plugin looks like - no Size rules:
[image: My windows rules plugin]

Comment: so what have you been doing with compiz? Have you been compiling or installing some non default plugins?

Comment: Well, not much. I installed 11.10 about a week ago. I have reset my compiz settings to default through ccsm and then tweaked some (not many and mainly only changing bindings) of the settings, but no compiling, no plugins. Sincerely, I have no idea how it could go away :-/.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Well, stil unsolved for me. I od not know what detail to add.

Comment: Strange, Size Rules are there out of the blue... (i would accept this as an answer were it not closed down:-)).